# Measure ASP.NET page load time

Tags: asp.net

I'm currently developing an ASP.NET application which uses a `MasterPage` and I want to measure my application webform's loading time and display that information to the client.

My current strategy involves using the `Application_BeginRequest` event associated callback (in the `Global.asax` file of my website solution), to start the measurement of the time spent on the server-side process (as follows)

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
   Context.Items.Add("Request_Start_Time", DateTime.Now);
}
```

and calculate the elapsed time on the webform's `OnPreRender` event associated callback, printing it on a placeholder  element (as follows)

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
   base.OnPreRender(e);

   TimeSpan tsDuration = DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)Context.Items["Request_Start_Time"]);
   ExecutionTime.InnerHtml = "<em>Server-side processing duration: " + tsDuration.TotalMilliseconds + " miliseconds.</em>";
}
```

is this the best way to measure loading time? Is there a more "elegant" way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for your time and cooperation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<%@ Page Trace="true" %> (or set this in web.config)

Enable tracing and check out the information in trace.axd (in the root of your website).

Then you could set timing points with:

```
Trace.Write("Start time intensive task");
Trace.Write("Stop time intensive task");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx

This is assuming "your client" want deep debug data.

Comment: As I referred, I'm using a Master Page and I'm not figuring out how to enable Trace on it, as it doesn't seem to have the "Trace" property. Could you please help me out with this?

Comment: You don't need to turn Tracing on page by page, just do in your web.config, and it will work for all pages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6915t83k.aspx But please don't keep this setting for production!

Comment: @markus "This Topic Is No Longer Available" @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6915t83k.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Your appproach seems to be exact enough, as long as you do not render very large control trees and you don't use server controls that do all their work in an overridden `Render` method (unexperienced server control authors tend to do exactly that...).

In that case, there is actually a way to render the actual rendering time ;-) Just use a `HttpResponse.Filter` object to fill a placeholder with the elapsed time. These filters are applied *after* the web form is rendered and before it goes to the client.

If you need this just for development, search for `trace.axd`, this will give you a lot of details not only about timing but also the request context, control tree structure and page size.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what metric you are looking to actually show.

1. Is this an overall "page loaded in __ seconds" type thing that will be there all the time?
2. Is this to determine if your coded solution meets requirements for a client, and not needed for production?

The answer to these two will dictate what makes the most sense when it comes to recording.  If your goal is #1, then I would say your method works.  If you are going for number 2, I could be looking at what Erwin has.