# Is there an easy way of obtaining the total page response time in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, page-lifecycle

commonly on say PHP or other web frameworks getting the total response time is easy, just start the timer at the top of the file and stop it at the end.

In ASP.Net there is the whole Page Lifecycle bit though so I'm not sure how to do this. I would like for this response time recording to take place in a master page and the response time show up in the footer of pages. What would be the best way of doing this? Is there something built in to ASP.Net for it? Is it even possible to include the OnRender time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it on the Global.asax, take a look at this [article](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Time_taken_to_render_a_page_in_ASP.NET.aspx)

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HttpContext.Current.Items["renderStartTime"] = DateTime.Now;
}

void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DateTime start = (DateTime) HttpContext.Current.Items["renderStartTime"];
TimeSpan renderTime = DateTime.Now - start;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<!-- Render Time: " + renderTime + " -->");
}
```

Comment: Setting the item index in the Application_BeginRequest is not needed. In the Application_EndRequest you can just reference HttpContext.Current.Timestamp. This value is set by the framework when the HttpContext object is created. In testing, this was the same value as the process above.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use

- Application begin_request and end_request in global.asax
- Use Firebug at client side to check the time it takes to load the page
- Use Tracing features

Some information available at:

[Measure ASP.NET page load time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395587/measure-asp-net-page-load-time)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Visual Studio Team System (perhaps other versions too now) you can also use the Visual Studio Profiler (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx) to profile what is taking the most time.