# Which pair of events gives me the estimate of server render time?

Tags: asp.net, performance

I create a stopwatch in the MasterPage constructor & start it. I update in PreRender a label to display the server-side render time. (I have javascript timers set up on the client side, and yes, client rendering is huge compared to server side rendering--but there are more things I can do about the server side time, should it be high)

I have the timer in the MasterPage so that I have access the label when it is time to write the # of milliseconds.

The time is consistently way lower than if I set the timer on Page constructor and write the time to console on the Page Unload event.

So what explains all this? Do I need to move my start/stop of the timers to different events? Is the time from Page construction to Page Unload covering time that shouldn't be counted in the time it takes to render that page on the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way of obtaining the total page response time in ASP.Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962554/is-there-an-easy-way-of-obtaining-the-total-page-response-time-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

When you starting Stopwatch in master/page constructor and finishing it on Unload this means that you are measuring the time of page life cycle and I can hardly agree that this is rendering (but yes, it includes rendering) because during page life cycle you can call database/services/other stuff up to `Thread.Sleep()`.

If we will consider "page rendering" as a time when controls are writing data to [Response.OutputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx) then we should take other approach. Following the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page rendering starts when first `Render` method is called and logically it ends when last `Render` method is called.

> Before rendering, view state is saved for the page and all controls.
>   During the rendering stage, the page calls the Render method for each
>   control, providing a text writer that writes its output to the
>   OutputStream object of the page's Response property.

In my opinion to measure rendering part of the page life cycle it is best to start and finish stopwatch inside overriden Render method of the page.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    base.Render(writer);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    // Set the value of rendering time in Page.Master
}
```

Again, why [Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.render%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)? From ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview:

> Render: This is not an event; instead, at this stage of processing,
>   the Page object calls this method on each control. All ASP.NET Web
>   server controls have a Render method that writes out the control's
>   markup to send to the browser.

---

But anyways I'm not sure why would you want to measure this manually. If tracing is [enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y89ed7z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) then you can assess page events duration via [trace.axd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or directly on page if you enabled `pageOutput` in configuration.

Comment: I think you are reading my question too literally. I time pages to get an objective feel for how long it took for a page to "show up" which starts when I click a link and finishes when I can interact with page-- some of that is server time, some of that is client time (browser processing), I'm not particularly interested in how long it took for the event called "Render". So I'm trying to pick a pair of events to time that measure the server time it takes to "create" a page.

Comment: @MatthewMartin yes, I read question too literally. For measuring the whole page life I would suggest to intercept `BeginRequest` and `EndRequest` events in `Global.asax` and there write time to response. I found that such question was asked before, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962554/is-there-an-easy-way-of-obtaining-the-total-page-response-time-in-asp-net?lq=1.