# Tracing in ASP.Net not working?

Tags: asp.net, trace

I followed the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395587/measure-asp-net-page-load-time) question and it isn't working.

I have the Trace enabled in my Web.Config.  I am calling Trace.Write in 2 places.  I am running through my application...and no Trace.axd file shows up.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not search for a file trace.axd, but call the page http://mydomain/trace.axd. As far as I know tracing just generates a dynamic ringbuffer containing the specified number of requests (default is 10).

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the trace option in web.config ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6915t83k.aspx

Because tracing is a security concern, this setting controls who can see the tracing.

Edit: I'm specifically referring to the pageOutput and localOnly attributes here ...

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon the same problem wondering why there was no output. However, there was output, but it was output after the closing html tag.

You might be able to view the contents by using a different browser which ignores such constraints, like Internet Explorer, or edit the html in Firebug or an equivalent and move the `html` and `body` tags.