# asp.net compare two pages' performance

Tags: asp.net, performance, compare

I have two pages and basically they show the same output but their style of programming is different. I want to compare the performance for these two pages like how long it takes the pages to load? If we perform Submit operation then how fast is on page 1 compare to page 2 and other things.

How can I compare the performance?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to set the Page trace attribute to true and observe the execution times for each of the pages event handlers, in the browser.

Here's an example of a similar question:

[Measure ASP.NET page load time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395587/measure-asp-net-page-load-time)

Answer (score 1):

How long it takes to submit is one thing and another one you may want to check is the rendering time. 
**The simplest idea** how to measure and compare performance could be writing clicking test(s) (for example with [web-driver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-webdriver)) if you do not have them for both pages and measure how quickly test could be execute (probably running it multiple times in a sequence). Such approach allows you not to simple measure how much time it takes to render html itself but also how long browser loads that html (and related resource) and processes it.

And it's completely different story if you want to collect and aggregate performance metrics from real users which I believe out of the scope of your question.

Answer (score 1):

For the pages you are trying to time, maintain two DateTime objects `dtStart` and `dtEnd`. Set dtStart to DateTime.Now in the `OnPreInit` method and `dtEnd = DateTime.Now` at the end of the `Render` method. You can then calculate a TimeSpan from the two timestamps and log the time wherever you are maintaining the load times.

Answer (score 0):

On both pages, add this Trace mode:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Trace="True" TraceMode="SortByTime" %>
```

when the pages render, at the bottom of the page, you will see a dump of all the timings of each and every ASP.NET page event. You can then see where the time difference is.

If you are interested in measuring client side rendering time, then you need to use some browser profiler. For ex, on IE 9, hit F12, go to the Developer Tool, go to Profiler and Click Start. Then refresh the page. then Stop. it will then show you where the expensive javascript function is.

Google chrome and Firebug has similar tool, even more powerful.

Helps?